# lodash find not working in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

```
npm install lodash
npm install @types/lodash

ng serve
```

```js
import { find, upperCase } from 'lodash';

console.log(upperCase('test')); // 'TEST'
console.log(find(items, ['id', id])) // TypeError: "Object(...)(...) is undefined"
```

I tried using `import * as _ from 'lodash'` instead or not using the `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand but nothing works.

I can't find any tutorial that mentions any additional steps for using lodash in an Angular project.

```
Angular CLI: 8.2.2
Node: 10.14.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.2

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.38.0
```

Comment: `find(items, ['id', id])`, but `items` is undefined...

Comment: `upperCase('test') // 'TEST'`, really, sometimes, I wonder why people load a library just to perform `"test".toUpperCase()`...

Comment: @JeremyThille Unless something spooky is going on `items` should be defined (`console.log` above `find` shows `Array [ {…}, {…} ]`). `upperCase` is just a demonstration that lodash is at least partially working.

Comment: I just tried with `const items = [{id:1},{id:2}]; console.log( find(items, ['id', 2]) )` and the output is `{ id : 2 }`. Looks like the problem is your input data

Comment: @JeremyThille You are correct. I tried a for-loop and noticed there was an ID mismatch. The earlier error message when I used `_.find` about some undefined Webpack import threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

We're using the lodash-es package and with this you can import single functions.

Install

```
yarn add lodash-es @types/lodash-es
// or
npm --save lodash-es @types/lodash-es
```

Use

```
import isArray from 'lodash-es/isArray';

const res = isArray(somevar);
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps in order to use loadash with Angular:

1. Install the loadash

   `npm install --save lodash`
2. Install the typings

   `$ npm install --save-dev @types/lodash`
3. Import the loadash

   `import * as _ from "lodash";`

   **Or**

   `import _ from "lodash";`

Run the example as:

```
const items =[{id: 10, name: "Alex" }, {id: 20, name: "Jane"}];
console.log(_.find(items, ['id', 10]));
```

Output for the above program would be:

```
{id: 10, name: "Alex" }
```